# run jar in cmd NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory

Tags: java, maven, cmd, jar

I used mvn packaged my jar and tried to run jarfile in cmd.
Java code works in my Intelliji IDEA but jarfile is not working in command line.

I got a JNI error before so I edited the target bytecode version to 8 to comply my java runtime environment 1.8.0. So I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory
    at main.Main.main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

please help, thanks!

Comment: To run that jar standalone, you need a 'fat jar' made with the Maven Shade or Maven Assembly plugin